# How to convert https url to File in Java?

Tags: java, file, https

I have an https url which is of String format. How can I convert it to File? I tried this but I'm getting error - `URI scheme is not "file"`

```
 public static File convertURLToFile(String strURL) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        File file;
        try {
            file = new File(url.toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            String message = "Error in converting url to file";
            throw new RuntimeException(message, e);
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: What was the URL used? Message is clear, your URL is not of kind `file:`.

Comment: My URL is https

Comment: Then it is not a file... What do you really want to achieve. Modify your question accordingly, to give us an example of the input and what you want to achieve with...

Comment: strURL = "https://gb-us-west-2-prod-doc-source.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/9295df64f21c15ff4b5beb4c95c348a2180"
I just want to convert this strURL to File, this URL is contains Excel File.

Comment: Do I need to download the file first?

Comment: Not clear what you want...

Comment: A `File` refers to local file so if you need a `File` instance e.g. for calling a certain API function you need to download the file and save it in the local file-system. https://stackoverflow.com/q/921262/150978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileUtils.copyURLToFile` worked well for me.

Reference - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile-java.net.URL-java.io.File-